# Is it possible to save void in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a button which changes the color of the `MainActivity` but this works only if the app it is open if I exit the app and open again it return to normal color which is white.
How to store with Shared Preferences do you have any idea how to do that because strings, int and boolean I can save but this function I don' have any idea.

This is my code.

MainActivity.class

```
public static final String Change_Color = "Change_Color";
private boolean switchOnOff;


  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   if (switchOnOff == true) {
        setColorGreyImageButton();
        } else if(switchOnOff == false) {
            setColorWhiteImageButton();
        }


if(id == R.id.menu_back_white) {
   saveColor();
} else if (id == R.id.menu_back_black) {
   saveColor2();
}

 public void setColorGreyImageButton() {
        settings.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
        voiceSearch.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
        share.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
        search.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
        mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

SharedPreferences in MainActivity

```
public void saveColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Change_Color, false);
    switchOnOff = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Change_Color, false);

}

public void saveColor2() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Change_Color, true);
    switchOnOff = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Change_Color, true);
}
```

Comment: Save a `boolean`. Read the `boolean`. Call `setColorGreyImageButton()` if the `boolean` is `true`.

Comment: Can you provide code ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have changed my question I have writed code based on your answer but it doesnt work.

Comment: You do not appear to be assigning a value to `switchOnOff`, and you do not appear to ever be reading your `"Color"` preference.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you provide a code for this please because for the moment I am little bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these methods in your activity class:

```
private boolean getChangeColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getPackageName() + ".change_color", false);
}

private void saveChangeColor(boolean changeColor) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Color", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getPackageName() + ".change_color", changeColor);
    editor.apply();
}
```

In `onCreate()` check the `boolean` value stored in `SharedPreferences`:

```
   switchOnOff = getChangeColor();
   if (switchOnOff) {
       setColorGreyImageButton();
   } else {
       setColorWhiteImageButton();
   }
```

and when you want to change the value in `SharedPreferences` call:

```
saveChangeColor(true);
```

or

```
saveChangeColor(false);
```

Comment: @Spritzig my answer was about saving and retrieving info to/from `SharedPreferences`, because this is what you asked for. Does this work?

Comment: This is working but it is not changing the colors, if you have any idea will help me otherwise I am trying to find a solution during we are chating.

Comment: @Spritzig the code in your question is irrelevant to this issue. Post another question with **all the relevant code**: how you are trying to change the color and the case where it works and the case where it does not.

Comment: This is my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943508/trying-to-change-colors-with-sharedpreferences-but-it-is-not-getting-in-the-righ